# My style sheet css don´t show lines in the console Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

What happened?, the console don´t show lines of document.css thanks.
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: can you refresh your browser and check again ??

Comment: I am not sure what the question is really asking, what lines?

Comment: if you are talking about the `style` attribute in your div-element (which would reflect the css rules), well ... it's how it works. CSS styling rules works different then HTML inline styling.

Comment: Is it what you are asking? => http://i.stack.imgur.com/57ZEh.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem.

The styles.css don´t show because I use the [Prefix free plugin](http://lea.verou.me/prefixfree/)

In his limitations says : "Unprefixed linked stylesheets won’t work locally in Chrome and Opera."

I disable this plugin for local testing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same situation before, all i had to do is to remove a jQuery plugin. i don't remember the name but that was converting external style as internal styles.

Try removing links to your external JavaScript files and look which plugin cause the problem.
Hope this helps :)